# Add notificationCenter observer to specific NSTextField - MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

For a MacOS app I'm building with Xcode/Swift, I'm trying to call a function when the value has changed in a NSTextField (while the user is typing). So I've added a notification center observer:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSTextDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(textField.stringValue)
    }
}
```

This works fine. But now I want it to apply to a specific NSTextField, so I set the object in the observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSTextDidChange, object: textField)
```

Now it suddenly doesn't work anymore, and I can't seem to figure out why. Just starting out with Xcode and Swift. I've been searching for a solution all weekend, but most answers I find apply to iOS apps, older versions of swift, Objective-C etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43371152/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NSTextDidChangeNotification` is one of `NSText`'s notifications, and `NSTextField` does not inherit from `NSText`. The reason you're seeing those notifications at all is because `NSTextField`'s uses field editor, which is an instance of `NSTextView`, which *is* a subclass of `NSText`, to do its actual editing, and the notification's `object` property will be the field editor rather than the original `NSTextField`.

If you register to receive `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification` notifications instead, you should be able to specify the text field as the `object` and have it work.

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach, with just `.isEditing` method on your selected UITextField (and Swift 5).

First, declare your Observers in viewDidLoad():

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Then

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if <YOUR_UITEXTFIELD_HERE>.isEditing {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                }
            }
        }
    }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
```